# Prevent Apache from deleting files on 500 error

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, webdav

I have the following problem when using Apache 2.2.16 running on Windows Server 2008 R2: I have the server configured as a WebDAV server for automated client software to upload files to. However if the network connection between the client and the server is lost then it takes a while for the connection to timeout and for Apache to generate an HTTP 500 error, once this error is generated Apache deletes the partially uploaded file that caused the error. This would be fine but the automated software will retry the upload, sometimes *before* the network connection has timed out. This has the effect that a correctly fully uploaded file will be deleted by Apache when the previous failed upload of the same file timed out.

Obviously this is highly undesirable behaviour because as far as the client is concerned the file was uploaded correctly. Is there a simple config change to prevent Apache from deleting uploaded files in the event of an upload failure or a 500 error occurring?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we found out that this issue was because Apache was rejecting the same message sent within five minutes of the failed message. We solved this in our upload client by putting in a configurable wait.

Hopefully that might help someone who has had the same issue. i admit it's a niche problem!